# Using Docusign with a PDF

Tags: docusignapi

I'm interested in using DocuSign. I ran the demo and I saw what appeared to be a PDF file. My document that I require signing is a PDF file. Several questions.

1. Do I have to re-make my PDF file with DocuSign?
2. Is it even possible to use a PDF or must I use some sort of private DocuSign file format?
3. Step 2 on the "how does it work" page states you need to indicate who needs to sign. Does that mean I need to specify the names of the persons going to sign the documents? I ask this because I do not know the names of the people before hand, they download a PDF file from my website, and the functionality I need is as simple having them sign the pdf file they download then re-upload it.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign accepts virtually any file type, but converts any file that you provide to PDF format (if it isn't already in PDF format). You can certainly provide files to DocuSign in PDF format; i.e., you don't need to convert your PDF files to any other format before submitting them to DocuSign.

Regarding question #3 -- typically you'd design your web app to collect the user's name and email address prior to calling DocuSign to initiate the signing of the document(s).  That way, when you make the API call to DocuSign to create the *envelope* and initiate the signing session, you include signer information (name and email address) in the API request.

Finally, if you're looking for a quick/easy way to collect signer info (name & email address) and get document(s) signed from your website, without having to build an API integration -- I'd suggest you checkout [DocuSign PowerForms](https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/features/powerforms). Based upon the information you've provided about your scenario, using PowerForms might enable you to achieve your goal of getting the document(s) signed. Please note though, even if you use PowerForms to get the document(s) signed, you'll still need to use either the API or [DocuSign Connect](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/connect-guide) to retrieve the signed document(s) so that you can store them on your web server.