# How can a user digitally sign a pdf file(using Docusign) which is in my server?

Tags: php, pdf, docusignapi, digital-signature

I am trying to digitally sign a pdf file(which is dynamically created using mpdf library). I am trying to use Docusign to sign the pdf file.

The pdf file is basically an agreement. The user will fill an HTML form and the sign this agreement digitally. I am a beginner in digital signatures, and I assume we need to use an API from docusign.

Do the user need to have a docusign account? How can we have the user add a digital signature to this pdf file? Do we need to have a developer account in docusign? It would be greatly beneficial if anyone could give me code samples. Thank you very much.

I saw this thread([Using Docusign with a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551560/using-docusign-with-a-pdf)) and got some idea about the solution, but if there are any code samples, that would be great.

Comment: To clarify: do you actually *want to sign with DocuSign* (as your question title indicates) or do you want to sign and merely *assume you need DocuSign* for that (as you seem to say in your question body:  "The user will fill an HTML form and the sign this agreement digitally. I am a beginner in digital signatures, and I assume we need to use an API from docusign.")?

Comment: @mkl, my apologies for the confusion. The workflow is that a pdf file(stored in the server) will be available for the user. The user will need to input his docusign digital signature in that file. How can this be done? Should we call an API for that?

Comment: Ah, so you are committed to docusign. Unfortunately I cannot help in that case, I'm not into their services and APIs.

Comment: @mkl, okay. No worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a lot of questions, lets see if I can help:

> Do the user need to have a docusign account?

The person who sends the document(s) to be signed needs a DocuSign account. The signer(s) and other recipients do not need an account.

> How can we have the user add a digital signature to this pdf file?

Do you really want a `digital signature` or is an electronic signature satisfactory? If you do want a digital signature, then your DocuSign account (for the sender) needs to be enabled to request a digital signature from the signer(s). To have this feature enabled on your free DocuSign Developer Account, first obtain an account via developers.docusign.com. Then send your account id along with your request to go-live@docusign.com

Once the digital signatures feature is enable, you request a digital signature when you identify the signer(s). This can be done via the DocuSign web tool or via the API. This [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/standards-based-signatures) provides more info.

> Do we need to have a developer account in docusign?

You do a developer account if you want to use the API to request the signatures. Developer accounts are free. See developers.docusign.com

If you want to request a digital signature via the web tool, you don't need a developer account. Just a DocuSign account with the Standards Based Signatures feature turned on.

> It would be greatly beneficial if anyone could give me code samples.

We have code examples for using the API to request signatures via email and via an embedded signing ceremony. See the left side navigation column of the [examples](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples) page.

Unfortunately those examples are requesting electronic signatures, not digital signatures. You'll need to use the SBS signatures documentation referenced above.

Ask another question on StackOverflow if you have difficulties combining the two.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Do you really want a digital signature or is an electronic signature satisfactory? - I require a digital signature. If I create my developer account and then enable to request a digital signature from the signer(s), does the API call actually sign the document with the user's signature? Also, can I retrieve the signed document from the API since I need to store it in my server.

Comment: When the signer signs, a digital signature will be added to the PDF. Yes, you can easily (via the API or via the web tool) download the digitally signed PDF. You cannot use the DocuSign eSignature API to sign a document on behalf of a signer. Your API program can, itself, digitally sign a document if you use the more specialized DocuSign Signature Appliance.